# JavaScript Arrays and Scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

This must be very simple but I've been at this far too long and I just cannot find a relevant answer anywhere.

It's quite simple, really.

When my code is like this:

```
/* functionsAndStuff.js */
var x = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];
function doStuff(){
    var value = x[0][0];
    return value; //BROKEN
}
```

Nothing happens. This code here, on the other hand, works out just fine:

```
/* functionsAndStuff.js */
function doStuff(){
    var x = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];
    var value = x[0][0];
    return value; //returns 1
}
```

The doStuff() function returns the value to index.html, a different page. index.html uses the function to do it's own thing.

Changing it up and doing this makes it work:

```
/* index.html */
var x = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];


/* functionsAndStuff.js */
function doStuff(){
    var value = x[0][0];
    return value; //returns 1
}
```

I suppose if I just define the matrix in index.html, my problem will go away... but that's a bit of a sloppy solution.

I have another array which starts off empty. This array is then later populated by splitting a string. This array is completely accessible. But I still can't access the x array at all, which is being filled in manually (ie hard coded).

Comment: x was probably modified before the function was called.

Comment: The first function works fine for me in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/UD8Zs/

Comment: Your first sample works perfectly fine. Most likely @Musa is right - something changing `x` before you call `doStuff()`, but without actual code that reproduces the problem it is not possible to confirm.

Comment: maybe adding alert(x); just before trying to get x[0][0] to see what is really in x at this very moment

Comment: x is never accessed, though. Not until it's used in doStuff(). I know it's SUPPOSED to work, but it ISN'T and its extremely frustrating because I can't figure out why.

Comment: @ForkSpoon, with what you have provided we can't do anything

Comment: @Alexander Even with the new information I just added? What more do you need?

Comment: @ForkSpoon, I think you misunderstood. As long as `x` is the problem, we couldn't care less about other variables. What you need to do is to provide more context concerning `x`, if you are unable to prepare a suitable snippet then you may want to provide it all. It's you choice though. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The first function you have listed works fine, at least in FF16.

```
var x = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];
function doStuff(){
    var value = x[0][0];
    return value; //BROKEN
}

alert(doStuff()); //returns 1
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UD8Zs/

Comment: I was also surprised by this being *broken*